# Freelancer Iphone development - Xcode warnings acceptable?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, warnings

A freelancer is developing an Iphone app for me.
The app works fine but I get 37 warnings when I load the source code in Xcode. 
Would you mind having a quick look and telling me is there are some warnings about which I should worry .

Thanks for your help !

```
yyy Group
Semantic Issue Group
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/FMDatabase/FMDatabase.m:313:74: Second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'char'; this va_arg has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'int'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/FMDatabase/FMDatabase.m:326:70: Second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'short'; this va_arg has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'int'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/FMDatabase/FMDatabase.m:329:78: Second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'unsigned short'; this va_arg has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'int'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/FMDatabase/FMDatabase.m:350:66: Second argument to 'va_arg' is of promotable type 'float'; this va_arg has undefined behavior because arguments will be promoted to 'double'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2598:31: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2599:31: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2600:31: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2601:31: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2602:31: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2605:171: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2606:171: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2607:171: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2608:171: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2609:171: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2791:40: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:2802:45: Direct access to objective-c's isa is deprecated in favor of object_setClass() and object_getClass()
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Twitter/SHKTwitter.m:63:17: Receiver type 'int' is not 'id' or interface pointer, consider casting it to 'id'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Twitter/SHKTwitter.m:63:16: Instance method '-boolValue' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/UI/SHKFormControllerLargeTextField.m:97:120: Class method '+sharerTitle' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/UI/SHKFormControllerLargeTextField.m:240:2: Instance method '-sendDidCancel' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/UI/SHKFormControllerLargeTextField.m:246:5: Instance method '-sendForm:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Format String Issue Group
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/FMDatabase/FMDatabase.m:943:45: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long'
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:745:180: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:746:134: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:752:98: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:773:114: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:786:114: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/JSONKit/JSONKit.m:795:114: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Core/Helpers/OAuth/OAMutableURLRequest.m:194:48: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'time_t' (aka 'long')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Core/SHK.m:523:54: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/SHKFacebook.m:87:53: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Flickr/LFHTTPRequest.m:460:72: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Flickr/LFHTTPRequest.m:469:72: Format specifies type 'unsigned long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Google Reader/SHKGoogleReader.m:245:65: Format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double')
Cocoa API Issue Group
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/FBRequest.m:152:29: Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/FBRequest.m:161:29: Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Twitter/SHKTwitter.m:610:21: Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Iphone App/yyy 3/yyy/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Vkontakte/SHKVkontakte.m:409:20: Using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant
```

Answer (score 5):

It appears that most of these warnings are from third party libraries being used in the project such as JSONKit and ShareKit.  Nothing too major pops out at me though personally.  Warnings can be produced between various versions of Xcode.

Comment: Agree with various versions of Xcode producing/not producing warnings.  My App might be warning-free on Xcode 4.3 and then spew all sorts of warnings on 4.5.  In fact, one of my apps does just that, and most of the warnings are from a JSON library I was using (as seems to be the case here)